# Node JS Runtime Errors

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.JS. While I am running with below commands, I am facing the issues. Can anyone help me to sortout this issues here.

admin6@admin6-desktop:~/Desktop/shraddha/postingData$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See npm help json for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use npm install  --save afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (postingData) 
version: (0.0.0) 
git repository: 
keywords: 
license: (BSD) 
About to write to /home/admin6/Desktop/shraddha/postingData/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "postingData",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "ERROR: No README.md file found!",
  "main": "recipes.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

"dependencies":

```
{
    "express": "2.5.11",
    "ejs": "0.7.2"
  },
```

"repository": "",
  "author": "aarna",
  "license": "BSD",
  "devDependencies": {}
}

I am getting below errors while running above in command line.

Is this ok? (yes) 
npm WARN package.json postingData@0.0.0 No README.md file found!

I am waiting for quick solution.

Thanks
Shraddha

Answer (score 1):

Can can safely ignore `npm WARN` messages, but in this case it's a very easy fix.  Just make a README.md file.

Comment: Hi, I have created that README.md file but getting the same issue again and again. Can you please guide me what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add some text in it as well. It worked for me. It is not a bad idea having a README file anyway. :)